# issues with 'a:link {color}' CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

i want to change color of all my link on the page but it won't work on chrome, works fine on opera. i don't get what's going on can you help me make it work on every browser ??

```css
a:link
{
  color: rgb(255, 169, 73);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lake Towada</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
  </head>

<body>
    <p>
      some text<a href="https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3775.html" target="-_blank">Oirase</a>
      some text<a href="https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3780.html" target="-_blank">the mountains</a>some more text
      </p>
</body>
```

Comment: works fine for me on chrome and firefox. you sure the style you include is valid and not returning a 404?

Comment: have you tried debugging using Chrome console?

Comment: Have you tried checking the `a:visited` property?

Comment: like @Roberrrt said, you might have to add `a:visited` to the be the same colour as `a:link` (i.e. `a:link, a:visited{...}` )

Comment: @BookOfZeus yes, I'm not using any font-style.

Comment: @YongQuan, I have not learned to do it yet.

Comment: @Roberrrt it has nothing to do with the visited property, I have it set it works fine.

Comment: @ochi, I need it to be a different color, this doesn't help and is not working anyway. thanks for all  your answeres but i'm kinda stuck ^^"

Comment: Hi, you might have to be more specific about what is not working.  I am running Chrome and I see the links in orange (the colour defined in the CSS) - do you mean it does not change color when you put the mouse over the link:? (i.e. hover) - otherwise, can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: @Meowsky On Chrome, press `CTRL + SHIFT + C` and click on the link element that you want to inspect. Then you can see what style is applied and cancelled on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Styling anchor links can be a bit tricky. There are several pseudo classes along with the basic `a` tag selector that can be used for styling that affect links based on their state.

```css
/* newly added in the CSS selectors Level 4 specification */
:any-link, p :any-link{
  color:black;
}

/* it is recommended to always have the pseudo classes it in this order */
:link{
  color:blue;
}
:visited{
  color:mediumvioletred;
}
:hover{
  color:mediumaquamarine;
}
:active{
  color:green;
}

/* lowest specificity, so it will not be applied */
a{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">This link starts out blue.</a></div>
<div><a href="https://www.google.com/">This link *might* be violetred in your browser.</a></div>
<div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">So might this.</a></div>
<div class="special"><a href="#">Hovering will turn the links aquamarine.</a></div>
<p><a href="#">This link is black in browsers that support the new pseudo class. It also won't have any hover effects.</a></p>
```

If you ever visited one of the links in your code snippet on your Chrome browser (but not Opera) it will have a different color.

Most likely one or two of the links in the code snippet I provided will already have a different color for you because you visited one of those sites in the past.

To achieve a consistent result, explicitely set both `:link` and `:visited` and be mindful of [selector specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

You can use `:any-link` to achieve consistent results, which is effectively the same as `:link,:visited` but keep in mind that not all browser support this newer pseudo-class yet and it has the same base specificity, so it needs to be declared *last* (This is the reason why the rule in the code snippet is only applied to the last link).